# How to highlight area between two lines? ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data frame containing variable and it's conf. interval

```
time x     x.upper   x.lower
   1 1.00     0.91      1.11
   2 1.03     0.92      1.13
   3 1.03     0.95      1.17
   2 1.06     0.90      1.13
```

I `ggplot` it:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df,aes(time,x))+
    geom_line(aes(y = x.upper), colour = 'red') +
    geom_line(aes(y = x.lower), colour = 'blue')+
    geom_line()
```

I want to highlight area between red and blue lines, smth similar to `geom_smooth()` function. How can I do it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A `geom_ribbon` is exactly what you need

```
ggplot(data = df,aes(time,x))+
    geom_ribbon(aes(x=time, ymax=x.upper, ymin=x.lower), fill="pink", alpha=.5) +
    geom_line(aes(y = x.upper), colour = 'red') +
    geom_line(aes(y = x.lower), colour = 'blue')+
    geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add a legend to identify the color of the blue and red lines?

Comment: use `geom_line (aes(y = x.upper, colour = 'upper'))` and `geom_line((aes(y = x.lower, colour = 'lower')` to automatically create colour scales and legend