# combining geom_ribbon when x is a factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

Leading on from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24419574/how-to-highlight-area-between-two-lines-ggplot).

I cannot generate the shaded area when my `x` is a factor.
Here is some sample data

```
time <- as.factor(c('A','B','C','D'))
x <- c(1.00,1.03,1.03,1.06)
x.upper <- c(0.91,0.92,0.95,0.90)
x.lower <- c(1.11,1.13,1.17,1.13)

df <- data.frame(time, x, x.upper, x.lower)

ggplot(data = df,aes(time,x))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=time, ymax=x.upper, ymin=x.lower), fill="pink", alpha=.5) +
  geom_point()
```

when i substitute `factor` into the `aes()` I still cannot get the shaded region. Or if i try this:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_ribbon(data = df, aes(x=time, ymax=x.upper, ymin=x.lower), fill="pink", alpha=.5) +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(time,x))
```

I still cannot get the shading. Any ideas how to overcome this...

Comment: I believe `geom_ribbon` works for continuous x values only.  A work around would be to treat the factor as continuous (`as.numeric(time)`) and then change the breaks/labels of the x axis using `scale_x_continuous`.

Comment: Can you suggest as a Solution,please

Answer (score 4):

I think aosmith was exactly right, you simply need to convert your factor variable to numeric. I think the following code is what you're looking for:

```
ggplot(data = df,aes(as.numeric(time),x))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=as.numeric(time), ymax=x.upper, ymin=x.lower),     
  fill="pink", alpha=.5) +
  geom_point()
```

Which produces this plot:

[image]

EDIT EDIT: Change x-axis labels back to their original values taken from @aosmith in the comments below:

```
ggplot(data = df,aes(as.numeric(time),x))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=as.numeric(time), ymax=x.upper, ymin=x.lower),     
  fill="pink", alpha=.5) +
  geom_point() + labs(title="My ribbon plot",x="Time",y="Value") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:4, labels = levels(df$time))
```

Comment: I think maybe the OP was asking for the axis tick labels.  Something like `scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:4, labels = levels(df$time))`