# Fill area between two point-lines R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, minmax

I have a [tibble](/questions/tagged/tibble) similar to the following one:

```
 Offensive <- tibble(OffenseFormation = c("A","B","C"),
                     yardas_mean = c(3,4,5),
                     yardas_min  = c(1,4,1),
                     yardas_max  = c(5,4,6))
```

I plot the lines with the following code (as you can see in the picture below):

```
 Offensive %>%
   pivot_longer(starts_with("yardas_"),names_to = "yardas") %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = OffenseFormation, y = value, group = yardas)) +
   geom_line(aes(colour = yardas)) + 
   geom_point(aes(colour = yardas))
```

[image]

What I want is fill the area between `yardas_min` and `yardas_max` lines.

I've already used the following ggplot orders:

- `geom_area(alpha=0.1)`
- `geom_polygon( aes(y = value, group = yardas), alpha = 0.1)`

and also read some previous post like these ones:

- https://mcfromnz.wordpress.com/2014/06/02/shading-between-two-lines-ggplot/
- [How to highlight area between two lines? ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24419574/how-to-highlight-area-between-two-lines-ggplot)

But no success, any help?

Thanks,

Alberto

Comment: When you say you had "no success" from the existing solutions, what exactly does that mean? What exactly did you try? What was wrong with the output or what error messages did you get?

Comment: No output error messages, I just don't get the area between the red and blue lines, I get other things. My aim is to fill the space between only those two lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you have discrete values as x axis. You can make a ribbon by adding continuous values in `geom_ribbon`:

```r
Offensive %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("yardas_"),names_to = "yardas") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = OffenseFormation, y = value, group = yardas)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = yardas))+
  geom_ribbon(data = Offensive, 
               inherit.aes = FALSE, 
               aes(x = 1:3, ymin = yardas_min, ymax = yardas_max), 
              fill = "grey70")+
  geom_line(aes(colour = yardas))+
  geom_point(aes(colour = yardas))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. That is what I was trying. But still one problem, I lose the green line. Anyway to either bring it to the front or make the shaded area transparent?

Comment: Using `alpha=0.1` instead `fill=gray` I get it. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: You're welcome ;). To bring back the green line and points, you can recall them after `geom_ribbon`