# Colour area between 2 lines in ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Similar questions have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24419574/how-to-highlight-area-between-two-lines-ggplot) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586635/shade-region-between-two-lines-with-ggplot), but I can't seem to get them to work for my example. If I have a plot that looks something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(100)
x <- seq(0, 20, length.out=1000)
x1 <- seq(0, 18, length.out=1000)
x2 <- seq(0, 22, length.out=1000)
dat <- data.frame(x=x, 
                  px = dexp(x, rate=0.5),
                  pxHi = dexp(x1, rate=0.5),
                  pxLo = dexp(x2, rate=0.5)
                  )

ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=px)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(aes(x= x, y = pxHi), col = 'red') +
  geom_line(aes(x= x, y = pxLo), col = 'blue') + theme_bw()
```

[image: example plot]

Im trying to shade in-between the red and blue lines. I tried using `geom_ribbon` but I cant seem to to get it to work correctly.

Any suggestions as to how I could do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you pointed out, you do want `geom_ribbon`:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(100)
x <- seq(0, 20, length.out=1000)
x1 <- seq(0, 18, length.out=1000)
x2 <- seq(0, 22, length.out=1000)
dat <- data.frame(x=x, 
                  px = dexp(x, rate=0.5),
                  pxHi = dexp(x1, rate=0.5),
                  pxLo = dexp(x2, rate=0.5)
)

ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=px)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = x, ymax = pxHi, ymin = pxLo), fill = "pink") +
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(aes(x= x, y = pxHi), col = 'red') +
  geom_line(aes(x= x, y = pxLo), col = 'blue') + theme_bw()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Thanks. I think I made my example too simple. Your code works perfectly for this, but in my actual data, I keep getting an `Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data` error. I'll keep trying!!

Comment: @Electrino you’re welcome. Yes, often times, creating a reproducible example of -your- problem is the most difficult thing to do without provide all the details of -your- problem. Maybe try masking your data? But please DO NOT modify the original question. Rather, just ask a new one.